# ServiceStack Redis NuGet Dependency Version Errors at Runtime

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

After running a package update with NuGet, I can no longer run my application. It builds just fine, but when run I receive:

`Could not load file or assembly 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e06fbc6124f57c43' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

This seems to result from the version number being incorrect, but I can find no way to fix it, as that number does not appear in any user-editable file. My .csproj is looking for `Version=4.0.0.0`, in fact. Changing this has no useful effect.

The first time I installed ServiceStack.Redis, I had to manually fix the References in my .csproj file to use the correct versions, but this time it seems that fix will not work.

I'm not sure if I don't understand how to use NuGet, or if these packages are just broken, but how do I get a working installation?

Edit - packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <packages>
      <package id="ServiceStack.Common" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net40" />
      <package id="ServiceStack.Interfaces" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net40" />
      <package id="ServiceStack.Redis" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net40" />
      <package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net40" />
    </packages>
```

Comment: Remove all your `ServiceStack.*` NuGet packages from your project, and then add them again. It looks like a version mismatch, you shouldn't have to alter any files manually. Then do a clean and rebuild all.

Comment: This was actually the first thing I tried, with no effect.

Comment: Can you post your `packages.config`?

Comment: Can you remove all the ServiceStack packages then install using this NuGet command `Install-Package ServiceStack.Redis -DependencyVersion Highest`?

Comment: In fact I have also tried that already, with identical result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have dirty dlls and need to do a **clean uninstall** of all ServiceStack packages. i.e.

- Remove all references of ServiceStack dlls from your projects
- Delete the NuGet `/packages` folder and **packages.config**
- Remove all **assembly binding redirects** from your App/Web.config
- Delete your `/bin` and `/obj` folders

Then install the packages again from NuGet, starting from this clean slate.

Comment: This fixed it, specifically checking for binding redirects.